# Como imprimir a mensagem de erro no Angular?

Tags: angular

Eu sou novo como programador Angular, faz pouco tempo que estou estudando e preciso muito de ajuda para resolver um problema no meu projeto Spring Boot com **Angular**. Estou querendo imprimir a mensagem da API Java no Angular.

Vou fazer passo a passo para conseguirem entender.

Observem a figura abaixo do **Postman**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que observassem os registros que já existem no banco, a minha API **Java** consegue salvar registros no banco, porém eu criei muitas regras de negócios na tabela **Estilos**, vou mostra uma das regras;

Por Exemplo, o sistema não permite que o usuário salve um registro que já existe no banco, se você para observar na figura acima o primeiro registro está com o nome de **Amber Lager**, e vou tentar salvar o mesmo registro para vocês verem o que acontece.

*Esse foi o registro submetido:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como o registro submetido já existe no banco de dados então a API Java dispara uma mensagem de erro como podem ver abaixo:

Gostariam que percebessem que existe a mensagem de erro do Usuário e do Desenvolvedor, o que estou precisando é da mensagem de erro do Usuário representado como **mensagemUsuario** e nela está escrito **"Nome do estilo já cadastrado"**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: **API Java está se comportando como esperado**

A mesma coisa acontece numa tela de Front-End, NOTEM, a mensagem em vermelho que é disparado logo abaixo da tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa mensagem de erro foi disparado pela minha API **Angular**, infelizmente sou inciante como programador Angular, a mensagem que deveria ser emita não seria essa da figura abaixo, tinha que ser a mensagem que está na API Java como **"Nome do estilo já cadastrado"**, essa mensagem de erro como podem ver na figura abaixo é uma mensagem genérica, ou seja, minha API Angular não sabe distinguir as mensagens de erro, e por conta disso qualquer erro que aparece no sistema ela sempre vai emitir essa mensagem de erro da figura abaixo, **pois é exatamente isso que não quero.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa mensagem de erro está configurada nesse arquivo abaixo:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { ToastyService } from 'ng2-toasty';

@Injectable()
export class ErroHandlerService {

  constructor(private toasty: ToastyService) { }

  handle(errorResponse: any) {
    let msg: string;

    if (typeof errorResponse === 'string') {
      msg = errorResponse;
    } else {
      msg = 'Erro ao processar serviço remoto. Tente novamente.';
      console.error('Ocorreu um erro', errorResponse);
    }

    this.toasty.error(msg);
  }

}
```

Perceba que a mesma mensagem que saiu no Postman também foi emitida no consoles do navegador de internet como podem ver na figura abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu conseguir encontrar na internet esse código parecido no GitHub, observem:

[REPOSITÓRIO](https://github.com/algaworks/curso-angular-rest-spring-boot-ui/blob/master/20.4-fazendo-deploy-em-producao-no-heroku/src/app/core/error-handler.service.ts)

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

import { NotAuthenticatedError } from './../seguranca/money-http';
import { ToastyService } from 'ng2-toasty';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandlerService {

  constructor(
    private toasty: ToastyService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  handle(errorResponse: any) {
    let msg: string;

    if (typeof errorResponse === 'string') {
      msg = errorResponse;

    } else if (errorResponse instanceof NotAuthenticatedError) {
      msg = 'Sua sessão expirou!';
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);

    } else if (errorResponse instanceof Response
        && errorResponse.status >= 400 && errorResponse.status <= 499) {
      let errors;
      msg = 'Ocorreu um erro ao processar a sua solicitação';

      if (errorResponse.status === 403) {
        msg = 'Você não tem permissão para executar esta ação';
      }

      try {
        errors = errorResponse.json();

        msg = errors[0].mensagemUsuario;
      } catch (e) { }

      console.error('Ocorreu um erro', errorResponse);

    } else {
      msg = 'Erro ao processar serviço remoto. Tente novamente.';
      console.error('Ocorreu um erro', errorResponse);
    }

    this.toasty.error(msg);
  }

}
```

Apesar de ter conseguido um bom modelo de código pra mim ajudar a imiprimir a mensagem de erro da API Java na API Angular mesma assim estou tendo dificuldade.

Observem novamente a mensagem erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode perceber que abaixo do Response tem o **"Ok":** false, logo abaixo tem o **status:** 400, mais baixo tem o **statusText:** "Ok", depois vem o **type:** 2, em seguida vem o **url:**"http://localhost:8080/estilos", por final o **_body:** "[{"mensagemUsuario":"Nome do estilo já cadastrado","mensagemDesenvolvedor":"com.algaworks.brewer.service.exception.NomeEstiloJaCadastradoException"}]

Então termos o:

1. OK
2. status
3. statusText
4. type
5. url
6. _body

Se eu for adaptar o código que encontre no repositório github na internet com meu projeto eu consigo encontrar no código todas menos o **_body**, eu fiquei impressionado com isso, foi uma droga mesmo, se eu conseguisse acessar talvez tivesse condições de resolver o meu problema.

====================================================

Eu tentei realizar a verificação assim, mas gerou erro no **type === 2**

```
else if (errorResponse instanceof Response && errorResponse.type === 2){
      msg = 'Ocorreu um erro ao processar a sua solicitação';
    }
```

================================================

Seguindo a sugestão de Pedro, colocando

```
salvar(form: FormControl) {
    this.estiloService.adicionar(this.estilo)
    .then(() => {
      this.toasty.success('Cerveja adicionado com sucesso!');
      form.reset();
      this.estilo = new Estilo();
    })
    .catch(erro => this.erroHandler.handle(console.log(erro)));
```

deu isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mais isso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que estou precisando é imprimir de alguma forma a mensagem de erro que vem da API Java que é **Nome do estilo já cadastrado** na tela do navegador.

Desculpe se fui muito extenso na minha explicação, mas foi necessário.

[Esse é meu repositório](https://github.com/wladyband/controle-de-cervejas/blob/master/brewer-ui/src/app/core/erro-handler.service.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara você verificou se essa condição `if (typeof errorResponse === 'string')` é verdadeira?
Pode copiar o código da chamada da função ErroHandlerService.handle

Comment: Pedro, não fui eu que notifiquei como negativo na sua sugestão, mas isso não resolve meu problema.

Comment: É porque assim, pelo o que eu entendi mostra o alerta de erro mas sempre com a msm mensagem, seria no caso a condição não sendo atendida, você teria que verificar se está passando para a função apenas a msg(que seria no tipo string e entraria na condição) ou o objeto Response

Comment: Mas se você perceber no meu código já existe essa verificação, e se eu for efetuar essa verificação que você está sugerindo vou está realizando uma verificação incorreta, preciso de alguma forma conseguir a verificação do _body ou conseguir dá um get na mensagem da API java.

Comment: Na verdade você não mudaria a verificação, só no retorno do método HTTP você passaria apenas a msg para a função ErroHandlerService.handle.
Você poderia copiar o método HTTP que é chamado?

Comment: Como faria isso?

Comment: Posta o método HTTP de salvar um estilo, que posso exemplificar.

Comment: Cara vi aqui teu repositório (agora que vi que você tinha colocado o link), foi como eu havia falado, no "estilo-cadastro.component.ts" na linha 39 você está passando o objeto erro, na verdade você teria que passar apenas a msg

Comment: Realmente essa sugestão que você deu realmente resolve parcialmente o problema, mas é só um paliativo, porque eu tenho mais outras duas regras de negócio nessa mesma tabela, e se eu colocar fixo como você sugeriu não terei condições de colocar as outras mensagens de acordo com a regra de negócio da API Java, teria mesmo que ser um get direto da API Java pegando do _body para acessar o conteúdo do Array mensagemUsuario.
E se ficar fixo a mensagem  estaria de certa forma  também inutilizando a classe error-handler.services.ts

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem, mas minha sugestão seria essa trocar `.catch(erro => this.erroHandler.handle(erro));` para `.catch(erro => this.erroHandler.handle(erro._body.mensagemUsuario));`

Comment: para este formulário, por exemplo, se o usuário aperta 5 vezes consecutivamente o submit nesse formulário ele dispara a exceção configurada na classe error-handler.services.ts, mas se a mensagem tiver fixa nesse formulário não vai retornar nada para o usuário, mas disparar uma mensagem de erro no consoles do navegador que para o usuário não serve

Comment: opa, calma que vou dá uma olhanda! rs

Comment: Essa sugestão quase chega perto, mas não resolveu, ele fez disparar a mensagem padrão do sistema, era bom que existisse uma forma de colocar esse código naquela classe error-handler.services.ts

Comment: Se não disparou a mensagem do estilo já cadastrado, dá um `console.log(erro._body.mensagemUsuario)` e verifica se tá certo o acesso a mensagem. Você só pode mover esse código para o error-handler.services.ts se tiver certeza que a msg sempre virá no `erro._body.mensagemUsuario`, pq senão terá que adicionar mais código para atender uma exibição de msg, de um objeto diferente.

Comment: pelo fato da classe error-handler.services.ts esteja gerenciando todos os erros do sistema é impossível gerar mensagens no console.log, mas mesmo assim eu fiz a tentativa e gerou a mensagem de erro "Ocorreu um erro undefined"

Comment: além de gerar a mensagem padrão do sistema.

Comment: O `console.log(erro._body.mensagemUsuario)` é no estilo-cadastro.component.ts, algo como isso `.catch(erro => {console.log(erro._body.mensagemUsuario);this.erroHandler.handle(erro._body.mensagemUsuario));} `

Comment: infelizmente não pegou!

Comment: Certo vi aqui que o seu _body é um array então tente isso `.catch(erro => {console.log(erro._body[0].mensagemUsuario);this.erroHandler.ha‌​ndle(erro._body[0].mens‌​agemUsuario));}`

Comment: gerou um errão mas em resume deu isso aqui  "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'mensagemUsuario' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mensagemUsuario' of undefined"

Comment: Em algum momento desses testes apareceu no console a msg correta? Se não tiver aparecido você vai ter que dar um `console.log(erro)` e inspecionar como acessa corretamente a msg e passar no handle

Comment: eu atualizei a postagem dá uma olhada por favor.

Comment: tenta esse cara `.catch(erro => this.erroHandler‌​.ha‌​ndle(erro.json().mensagemUsuario))`

Comment: não deu certo, infelizmente.

Comment: Verifica o console
`.catch(erro => {
    console.log(erro.json().mensagemUsuario);
    this.erroHandler‌​.ha‌​ndle(erro.json().mensagemUsuario))
})`

Comment: deu a mensagem de erro undefined.

Comment: Cara volta o "estilo-cadastro.component" do jeito q você fazia antes e no "erro-handler.service.ts" coloca isso: `handle(errorResponse: Response) {
    let msg: string;
    let errorMsg: string = errorResponse.json()[0].mensagemUsuario;

    if (typeof errorMsg === 'string') {
      msg = errorMsg;
    } else {
      msg = 'Erro ao processar serviço remoto. Tente novamente.';
      console.error('Ocorreu um erro', errorResponse);
    }

    this.toasty.error(msg);
  }`

Comment: Vou considerar como correta, mas você me ajudou bastante a encontrar a solução, eu vou bosta a solução aqui, pois encontrei como resolver, graças a você e um grupo de colegas meus, tudo bem?

Comment: Show de bola, o importante é você ter ido atrás e pensado em uma resposta.

Answer (score 0):

A alteração tem que ser feita somente no método adicionar no arquivo **estilo.service.ts** com essa alteração o gerenciador de erros fica responsável em dá um get na mensagem de erro da API Java, ela já tinha sido configurada para isso mesmo.

```
adicionar(estilo: Estilo): Promise<Estilo> {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post(this.estilosUrl,
        JSON.stringify(estilo),  { headers })
      .toPromise()
      .then(response =>  response.json())
      .catch( response => {
          if ( response.status === 400 ) {
              const responseJson = response.json();
              if ( responseJson[0].mensagemUsuario === 'Nome do estilo já cadastrado' ) {
                  return Promise.reject('Nome do estilo já cadastrado');
              }
          }
          return Promise.reject (response);
      });
   }
```

Depois das modificações realizadas funcionou perfeitamente.